# Azure Functions: How can I import classes from other folders to __init__.py file of an Azure time trigger function?

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio, import, azure-functions

I am trying to automatize the upload of some data through an Azure Timer Trigger function.
To do so, I am importing from all scripts the classes I have built in order to run the code in the pre-defined **init**.py file.

However, no import seems to work:

I have tried with the following:

1.

```
from ..Project.AWS.S3_uploader import S3_Uploader
```

2. from Project.AWS.S3_uploader import S3_Uploader

but in both cases I face some error. In the first case I get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

In the second case I get:

```
    from Project.AWS.S3_uploader import S3_Uploader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Project'
```

Whereas if I only try to import S3_Uploader, I get an error.

How can I fix this for the **init**.py file to successfully import my classes?
By reading azure's documentation I even added an **init**.py file inside each folder, but it doesn't seemt to work.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you!
Below the picture of the environment I am working in:
[Environment in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePOEV.png)

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded in solving the issue by removing subfolders containing the code and putting all .py files in an unique shared_code folder[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck9Py.png)